# What is ?MODULE

Tags: erlang

I am working through the tutorial here

http://alexmarandon.com/articles/mochiweb_tutorial/

One of the source files contains

```
start(Options) ->
    {DocRoot, Options1} = get_option(docroot, Options),
    Loop = fun (Req) ->
                   ?MODULE:loop(Req, DocRoot)
           end,
    mochiweb_http:start([{name, ?MODULE}, {loop, Loop} | Options1]).
```

What does `?MODULE` denote?

Comment: ?MODULE is a predefined macros - the name of the current module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?MODULE` is one of predefined macros in Erlang and it expands into the name of the current module as an atom.

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id84790